# Crystal reports different size of page footer

Tags: crystal-reports

I have read so much answers about this, but none work for me.

I have a report with diferent size of page footer for each page. So the printing is like this

```
|Header1   |Header1
|Detail1   |Detail3
|Detail2   |Detail4
|Footer2   |Footer1
|          |Footer2
```

I want it to be like this:

```
|Header1   |Header1
|Detail1   |Detail4
|Detail2   |Detail5
|Detail3   |Footer1
|Footer2   |Footer2
```

I mean, I want the detail to be as fas as it can to then let the small footer there.

I have tried this:
[Crystall report with different size footer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2010875/crystall-report-with-different-size-footer)

But don't work for me.

Comment: I couldn't understand exaclty... can you show in design how would you like to view your report.

Comment: @Siva The firts colum is the firts page and the second columan is the second page. I want the detail to have as much rows as the page footer let him.

Comment: See for a page there will be only one page footer and there can be many detail section that can fit the size of the page...now tell me you want to limit the number of detail rows? as to the extent I know you can't increase page footer as there will be only one per page.

Comment: @Silvia That is. In the firts page I have one page footer, but in the second one i have 2. So i want to fill the space that the page footer left with details. The problem is that Crystal report reserves the space for the larger footer.